# default git commit behavior to --allow-empty

Tags: git, commit

I would like to get `git commit` to have the `--allow-empty` flag by default (not with an alias).

I search in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) but I didn't find anything about it.

Is there any `gitconfig` command that can change this?

Comment: I am not sure, but as a workaround you could set up a git alias for that.

Comment: @lucidbrot it works but I doesn't default the command itself to `--allow-empty` .

Comment: I am interested to see if someone finds an answer for your specific question. Out of curiosity: why do you want to change the default command and not an alias?

Comment: Btw: you could always pull the git source code, customize the function that handles commits, and build a new binary for yourself.

Comment: it's just to use the real command instead of an alias. An alias forces you to remember one more command and this can quickly become difficult when you have a lot of them.

Comment: I think the simplest would be to just remember the `--allow-empty` flag then, that's what I do. Alternatively, an alias like `committ` with a second `t` should be easy enough to remember. If you really want to, you can probably change the check [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/90d242d36e248acfae0033274b524bfa55a947fd/builtin/commit.c#L1035) and build git for yourself but that might come with unexpected side-effects like e.g. on `git cherry-pick`. I searched the `git-config` for all occurrences of `commit.` and `empty` and didn't find an existing option.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I think the safer and simpliest way to do it is just do make an alias. Hope git will implement this one day.

Comment: Not an answer, but I wonder, what's the use case? It's extremely rare I want to make empty commits, so I'm interested in finding out why you want that enabled by default. In my case, an empty commit usually means I've made a mistake...

Comment: @joanis I make exactly one empty commit, for which the manual override is perfectly fine. Immediately after making a new repo with `git init`, I do `git commit --allow-empty -m NIL` to create a null-terminating commit.  This commit makes it possible to rebase/rewrite all subsequent commits. The first git commit itself resists rebasing activities because it doesn't have a parent to be able to express "the hash before that commit".

Comment: @Kaz Ah, I see. That does make some sense. Although you might want to know that you can pass `--root` to `git rebase` to be able to rebase the (parentless) initial commit too.

Comment: @joanis It's too awkward to work into scripts. Also inconsistent. in `git filter-branch` you have to use `--all`, separated by `--`.  Basically you need a shell function which converts an argument like `HEAD~3` into `--root` or `-- -all` in circumstances when it refers to one commit before the root commit.

Answer (score 1):

A quick skim of the [git-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) docs does not reveal such a specific option.

However, you can specify a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) that does this:

```
# the --global flag means this works now everywhere, not just in the current repo.
git config --global alias.committ "commit --allow-empty"
# Now use like this:
git committ -m "my empty commit, with a message"
```

<sub>While I was writing this answer, the question was edited. I am leaving this here for completeness since future visitors might be happy with this.</sub>

I gave it a try to overwrite `alias.commit` itself, without the additional `t`. This does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @DevinRhode what?

Comment: @endo.anaconda Thanks for the edit, but I believe what you did makes the answer no longer work. At least I attempted it and it seemed to have no effect. Rolled back for now.